# When is matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels preferred over matplotlib.pyplot.xticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a guide on when to use [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) and when to use [matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)? To me it seems like `matplotlib.pyplot.xticks (plt.xticks)` get's the job done quicker since it allows to label the ticks in the same line. Am I missing something? Is there an advantage in defining the axis separately?

Comment: typically I use set_xticklabels when I am doing so. I will use .xticks when I want to pull information from the xticks section (which I typically don't ever do). At the end of the day as long as you get your intended goal I don't believe it has a big impact.

Comment: In general, the object-oriented interface is recommended over the pyplot interface.

Comment: In recent Matplotlin, you should almost never use `set_xticklabels`, but rather `ax.set_xticks(ticks, labels=the_labels)`.  This ensures that the two are the same size and helps ensure they refer to the same ticks.  Its possible to have absolute nonsense if you just label the ticks.